# Trace of stress tensor in 2D average null energy condition

Tags: metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, conformal-field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, trace

I was looking through Zamolodchikov's derivation of the $c$-theorem and stumbled across an equation which says the following -

$$\Theta = T^\mu_\mu = 4T_{z\bar{z}}.$$

As far as I understand, for two null coordinates $z = t + iy$ and $\bar{z} = t - iy$ in 2D, the stress tensor $T_{z\bar{z}} = T_{\mu \nu}z^\mu \bar{z}^\nu$. But here there can only be one index for $z$. So I do not realise how the trace of the stress tensor can be written as is shown in the expression. Could someone kindly show me the steps even if they seem trivial?

Comment: Hi Sahil Saha. Welcome to Phys.SE.  Do you know that the 2D metric tensor $g_{z\bar{z}}=\frac{1}{2}$ is off-diagonal in the $(z,\bar{z})$ coordinates?

Comment: @Qmechanic that it will be off diagonal seems to be okay, I do not understand the 4 factor in front, or how the scaling dimensions make sense

Comment: Link to abstract page? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic [link](https://inspirehep.net/literature/2713647) Section 2.2, Page 6, below equation 2.9